# When I upgrading Magento 2.4.4 I am getting Deprecated Functionality: Return type of Composer\Repository\CompositeRepository::count()

Tags: magento, magento2

When I upgraded Magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.4, I got a php8.1 deprecated functionality error.

PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of Countable: Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Return type of Composer\Repository\CompositeRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/CompositeRepository.php on line 180 in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of PHP 8.1, you have to fix the return type of the functions count(). We need to modify 2 files.

Change public function count() to public function count(): int

Goto => \vendor\composer\composer\src\Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository.php   (line 277)

```
public function count(): int
{
    if (null === $this->packages) {
        $this->initialize();
    }

    return count($this->packages);
}
```

Goto => vendor\composer\composer\src\Composer\Repository\CompositeRepository.php  (line 180)

```
public function count(): int
{
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($this->repositories as $repository) {
        /* @var $repository RepositoryInterface */
        $total += $repository->count();
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue. Any solution without manually modifying the vendor folder?

Comment: Ahm, are you recommending to use core hacks in vendor/ to fix this? That's definitely the way to go for. The solution is to update all require and require-dev dependencies to the latest version. See the earlier posts.

Comment: Also need to update in vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/FilterRepository.php:188  public function count(): int

Answer (score 7):

I solved in this way (by composer 2.3.5):

`composer2 require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update`

`composer2 update`

```
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 0 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals
  - Upgrading composer/composer (2.1.0 => 2.2.18)
  - Upgrading magento/composer-root-update-plugin (1.1.2 => 2.0.2)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading composer/composer (2.2.18)
Gathering patches for root package.
Gathering patches for dependencies. This might take a minute.
  - Upgrading composer/composer (2.1.0 => 2.2.18): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading magento/composer-root-update-plugin (1.1.2 => 2.0.2): Extracting archive
```

Using the "require-dev" libs taken from Magento 2.4.4 composer.json https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.4/composer.json

"require-dev": {
"allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.5.0",
"dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~3.3.0",
"lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
"magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
"magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.7",
"pdepend/pdepend": "~2.10.0",
"phpmd/phpmd": "^2.9.1",
"phpstan/phpstan": "~1.2.0",
"phpunit/phpunit": "~9.5.0",
"sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
"squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.6.0",
"symfony/finder": "^5.2"
}

Answer (score 4):

just update the composer.json with this packages in require

```
"require": {
    "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
    "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "^2.0",  
},
```

Also, Use latest composer mine was ( 2.3.10)

Comment: Official requirement is to use composer 2.1.x for Magento 2.4.4 - please read Magento guidelines: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is that you haven't updated all your dev-requires to the lastest from 2.4.4. It turns out these lock the composer/composer module to 2.0.x if they aren't updated.

Comment: Can you give details how this need to be done?

Comment: What I usually do is browse to https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/composer.json (for 2.4.5) and composer the deps. Do NOT take over all deps from the composer file though. Some of them are removed again during a release. If you want to be a 100% sure about the most up-to-date composer file, run a fresh install and then compare things from there.

Comment: Point for you! After update DEV it started working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No worries. I was facing silimar issue and fixed by updating the composer package.

composer require composer/composer:~2.2.0 -W

Answer (score -1):

Just update composer to version 2.3.9 - in this version count method contains type

Comment: Official requirement is to use composer 2.1.x for Magento 2.4.4 - please read Magento guidelines: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html